# How do i pass a variable to carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, composite, image-upload

I have a question for create a combined photo.
I want to create a composite image file and I need to get a value from ImageUploader using gem carrierwave.
One image is like background image, and another is a png file which is user uploaded and i need the name this one.

I'm sure it will be works if i could get a file name but i couldn't get a file name from ImageUploader.

**items_controller.rb**

```
$mockup_image = @plain_product_color.mockup_image
```

**image_uploader.rb**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
// 
private

mockup_image = $mockup_image
base_image = MiniMagick::Image.open("#{Rails.root}/public/mockup_images/#{mockup_image}")
```

I using this global variables "$mockup_image" and this is work(of  course) but i need to pass a variable.

Please anyone kindly some advice for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can pass upload variables through the `model`, since the `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` contains the `model reference` is the instance of `ActiveRecord` which mount to that Uploader.

```rb
class User
 mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
 attr_accessor :background_image
end

class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 process :composite
 def composite
   manipulate! do |image|
    base_image = MiniMagick::Image.open(model.background_image)
    image.composite(base_image) do |c|
      # ...
    end
   end
 end
end
```

now we can set `background_image` on controller

```rb
# controller
def create
 user.background_image = # background image path
 user = User.new(params) # avatar = params[:file]
 if user.save
 ...
end
```

**However**, as you can see, we're bloating the `model` with the `ui parameters`, so that the better way that we encapsulate the user avatar ui decorator (background image, rotate, blur, ...) into an object

```rb
class AvatarDecorator
 attr_accessor :background_image, :round, :rotate #...
 def initialize(options={}) # or you can create a builder pattern
   background_image = options[:background_image]
   # ...
 end
end

class User
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  attr_accessor :avatar_decorator
end

class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 process :composite

 def composite
   set_background if model.avatar_decorator.background_image
   # ...
 end

 def set_background
  manipulate! do |image|
   # ...
  end
 end
end

# controller
def create
 user.avatar_decorator = AvatarDecorator.new({background_image: "..."})
 # ...
end
```

Comment: Hi Lam!
Thank you very much for your answer. Your advise is totally help me and i could make it as what i wanted. I was lack of knowledge an initializing in the model. 
Thanks again and sorry for my late reply. I was struggling for it tho!